# What kind of owl is Hedwig?

Tags: harry-potter, animals

In book one, she’s described as being a snowy or white owl.

Do we know what species she is in either the book or the movie?

Comment: A snowy owl is a species of owl. I think you might be confused and thought "snowy" meant "white" in this context? Because you literally listed the answer in your question. :)

Comment: @Theik Indeed, but at least I've come up with some more interesting stuff for my answer than just a quote saying she's a snowy owl :-)

Comment: Related: [Who played Hedwig?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/105190/10622)

Comment: @unor Yes, Himarm posted both these questions within minutes of each other.

Comment: @randal'thor: I know (the link’s not intended for Himarm but for any reader interested in Hedwig, and finding out more about the topic, as the species and the actual animals used in the movie are closely related).

Comment: Let me just add that a snow owl also takes an important role in Jules Verne, *Indes Noires*.  You can see that owl in Jules Férat's beautiful engravings: http://jv.gilead.org.il/rpaul/Les%20Indes%20noires/images/030.jpg , http://jv.gilead.org.il/rpaul/Les%20Indes%20noires/images/045.jpg .  Apparently it's a popular species for an intelligent pet in fiction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### She is a snowy owl (*Bubo scandiacus*).

"White owl" is just a description of her, but "snowy owl" is actually a [species of owl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowy_owl), native to the Arctic. It is the only species of owl that is predominantly white with black markings, and therefore unmistakable. Here's a quote to confirm that this is Hedwig's species:

> Harry now carried a large cage that held a beautiful snowy owl, fast asleep with her head under her wing.
>   <sub>-- *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*</sub>

Here are two pictures of snowy owls (female on the left, male on the right):

[[image: snowy owl female[1]]
[image: snowy owl male]

In the films, Hedwig is played by *male* snowy owls, which are whiter and also smaller, making them easier for young actors to handle. You can see this from comparing the follow shot of film-Hedwig to the two pictures above:

[image: Hedwig]