# Who played Hedwig?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, animals

In the Harry Potter movies, was their a specific owl, or owls that played Hedwig? What are their name/names and in what movies did they appears?

Comment: @theik you know there were multiple owls used right? Much like with almost every animal actor.

Comment: @CandiedMango Yes, in fact, there were 9 according to the article. "He was the more enthusiastic of the 9 owl actors that played Hedwig". My point being that this question shows zero research effort, google has the answers quite easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There were actually at least eight different animal actors used to portray Hedwig throughout the Harry Potter movies, but Gizmo seems to have been the primary animal actor.

[This article about animals in the HP movies explains](http://www.petplace.com/article/dogs/news-videos-fun/movie-reviews/meet-harry-potters-animals):

> Seven were needed to play Hedwig, the owl Hagrid purchased for the young wizard prodigy: named **Gizmo, Kasper, Oops, Swoops, Oh Oh, Elmo and Bandit.**

This [other article](http://www.visitbritainblog.com/blog/2014/04/02/we-meet-hedwig-the-owl/) mentions an eigth - White Terror Of The North. Why he was not mentioned in the other article is not clear, but he did not appear in *The Sorcerer's Stone*.

> He starred in all the Harry Potter movies but the first

This same article mentions that there were nine owls used, but does not identify the others by name.

> He was the more enthusiastic of the 9 owl actors that played Hedwig

The book [The Animal Movies Guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=dGYzZLrBrS4C&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=gizmo+kasper+oops+swoops+hedwig&source=bl&ots=uExJ2BOvuA&sig=2jNzloIyAHejJ4n_ZQS7ICWyvto&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBWoVChMI5uX_scvEyAIVzKUeCh1V9Qsj#v=onepage&q=gizmo%20kasper%20oops%20swoops%20hedwig&f=false) mentions that Gizmo was the primary animal actor during *The Sorceror's Stone*.

> Harry's own owl familiar is a snow named **Hedwig, who was played mainly by Gizmo** (Gizmo was doubled by Kasper, Oops, Swoops, Oh-Oh, Elmo, and Bandit).

[This interview with the animal trainer for two of the HP movies](http://www.scholastic.com/browse/article.jsp?id=5802) backs this up

> Q: For Harry's owl—Hedwig#151how many owls played Hedwig, or did you use just one?
>
> Gary: **There really is just one Hedwig—his real name is Gizmo.** He has a couple of helpers that help him out with the different things. We have a lighting stand-in, so he doesn't have to do all of the lighting. And we have a couple of owls that will help him with his flying shots, so he doesn't have to do all of the flying shots himself.

HP Wikia mentions the possible ninth owl, [Sprout](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sprout_%28owl%29), but the linked source does not actually make any mention of an owl by that name.

Comment: Huh. I was just researching all this to answer the other Hedwig question :-)